# Golang - Override JSON tag of embedded field

Tags: json, go, struct

Let's say I have the following types:

```
type Inner struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2"`
}

type Outer struct {
    Inner 
    Field2 string `json:"-"`
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish with this is to allow having a type (`Outer`) that includes all of the fields in an embedded type (`Inner`), but overrides one of the fields to not be marshalled in JSON. This does not work, and calling `json.Marshal(Outer{})` returns:

```
{"field1":"","field2":""}
```

Is there any way to do this in Go that will instead return this?

```
{"field1":""}
```

Comment: There is no way to do this in the standard library using tags. You can implement a custom marshaler for `Outer` to remove the field.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/l6a4FjJw2Ew) (the key is that the output tag has the same name):

```
type Inner struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2"`
}

type Outer struct {
    Inner
    NameDoesNotMatter string `json:"field2,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    j, err := json.Marshal(Outer{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("1: %s\n", j)

    v := Inner{
        Field1: "foo",
        Field2: "bar",
    }
    j, err = json.Marshal(Outer{Inner: v})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("2: %s\n", j)
}
```

Output:

```
1: {"field1":""}
2: {"field1":"foo"}
```

I found [this article](https://attilaolah.eu/2014/09/10/json-and-struct-composition-in-go/) very useful when looking into how to manipulate JSON output using struct composition.