# Override Spanner tag of embedded field

Tags: go, struct, google-cloud-spanner

Let's say I have the following types:

```
type Inner struct {
    Field1 string `spanner:"field1"`
    Field2 string `spanner:"field2"`
}
```

```
type Outer struct {
    Inner 
    Field2 string `spanner:"-"`
}
```

And spanner table `"some_table"` with only one column with name `"field1"`

What I am trying to accomplish with this is to allow having a type (`Outer`) that includes all of the fields in an embedded type (`Inner`), but overrides one of the fields to not be used in `spanner.InsertStruct()`. This does not work, and calling

```
spanner.InsertStruct("some_table", Outer{})
```

returns error:

> "Failed to apply mutation: spanner: code = "NotFound", desc = "Column not found in table some_table: field2""

It tries to insert
`{"field1":"","field2":""},`
but I want to insert
`{"field1":""}`

There is similar question to this with JSON([Golang - Override JSON tag of embedded field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60083914/golang-override-json-tag-of-embedded-field)), but it's solution doesn't work for spanner(there is no omitempty in spanner field tags), so maybe there is some other way to make this work?

Comment: I think a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be useful here.

Comment: Does it make sense now? I am not experienced with the stack overflow, sorry for not making it clear on the first try.